# How to load xml into webbrowser from richtextbox using vb .net?

Tags: xml, vb.net, xslt, webbrowser-control

I am very new to vb but i will try to explain my situation.

I have a button that loads an xml file into a richtextbox using the openfiledialog. I then use the XmlTextReader to format the xml for easy reading (e.g. tag names and attributes appear in different colors).

All of the above works great! What i need to know is how to view the richtextbox.text in the webbrowser when the textchanges in the richtextbox. This is my code so far:

```
Private Sub RichTextBox1_TextChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As     System.EventArgs) Handles RichTextBox1.TextChanged
    Dim txtHTML As String = RichTextBox1.Text

    'option 1 this works with transformation but is loaded from saved file e.g. C:\file.xml
    WebBrowser1.Navigate(TextBox1.Text)


    'option 2 this works without transformation
    WebBrowser1.DocumentText = txtHTML

End Sub
```

Currently i can load the xml into the webbrowser using the webbrowser.navigate but this only loads the file from the drive (see option 1 above). I can also load the webbroswer using the webbrowser.documenttext but this does not perform the xslt transformation that i require (see option 2 above).

Does anyone know how to load the richtextbox.text into the webbroswer as xml?

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick.

```
Private Sub RichTextBox1_TextChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As     System.EventArgs) Handles RichTextBox1.TextChanged

Dim txtHTML As String = RichTextBox1.Text

txtHTML.Text = WebBrowser1.DocumentText


End Sub
```